# With $z\in \mathbb C$ find the maximum value for $\lvert z\rvert$ such that $\lvert z+\frac{1}{z}\rvert=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

> With $z\in \mathbb C$ find the maximum value for |z| such that 
>   $$\left\lvert z+\frac{1}{z}\right\rvert=1.$$
>   Source: List of problems for math-contest training.

**My attempt:** it is easy to see that the given condition is equivalent
$$\lvert z^2+1\rvert=\lvert z\rvert$$ 
and if $z=a+bi$,
\begin{align*}
\lvert z\rvert&=\lvert a^2-b^2+1+2ab i\rvert=\sqrt{(a^2-b^2+1)^2+4 a^2b^2}\\
&=\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)^2+2(a^2-b^2)+1+4a^2b^2}\\
&=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)^2+2(a^2-b^2)+1}\\
&=\sqrt{\lvert z\rvert^4+2(a^2-b^2)+1}
\end{align*}
I think it is not leading to something useful... the approach I followed is probably not useful.

Hints and answers are welcomed.

Comment: Apologies for the unnecessary edit

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $z + \frac{1}{z} = e^{it}$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then solving for $z$ gives
$$z = \frac{e^{it} \pm \sqrt{e^{2it} - 4}}{2} = e^{it} \cdot \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4 e^{-2it}}}{2}.$$
Therefore,
$$ |z| = \frac{1}{2} \left| 1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4 e^{-2it}} \right| \le \frac{1}{2} \left( |1| + |\sqrt{1 - 4 e^{-2it}}|\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \sqrt{1 - 4 e^{-2it}} \right)\le \\
\frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \sqrt{|1| + |4 e^{-2it}|}\right) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
On the other hand, if we set $t := \frac{\pi}{2}$ so that $e^{-2it} = -1$ then we will get equality.  Therefore, the maximum value of $|z|$ is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which is achieved for $z = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} i$.  (In fact, a slight refinement of the argument will show that equality holds, i.e. the maximum is achieved, if and only if $z = \pm \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} i$.)

Comment: It seems an interesting approach, can you expand a little bit more... how this can lead to the maximum $|z|$.

Comment: OK, I've filled in how the rest of the argument goes.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$|z| = |z^2-(-1)|\geq |z|^2-|-1|$$

Write $r=|z|$ and we have $$r^2-r-1\leq 0\implies r\in [0,r_2]$$ where $$r_{1,2} ={1\pm \sqrt{5}\over 2} $$

So $r\leq \displaystyle{1+ \sqrt{5}\over 2}$

Answer (score 1):

The reverse triangle inequality implies that $|z^2+1|\geq ||z^2|-1|$ so that if $|z|^2\geq 1$ we see that 
$$|z|\geq |z|^2-1$$
By solving this inequality using the quadratic formula, we see that $|z|\leq \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$, so the maximum must be less than $\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$. We see that this maximum is attained by setting $z=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: If $z = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})$ then $z^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}(-1 + \sqrt{5})$ and $|z + z^{-1}| = \sqrt{5} \ne 1$.  The maximum is attained when $z = \pm \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5}) i$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the dual problem. Assume that the solution of the problem occurs at $z = re^{i\theta}.$ Consider
$$
F_r(t) = |re^{it}+r^{-1}e^{-it}|^2 = r^2 + r^{-2} + e^{2it}+e^{-2it} = r^2+r^{-2}+2\cos 2t.
$$ If $z= re^{i\theta}$ is the maximizer, we claim that $F_r'(\theta)=0$. That is, given $|z|=r$, the angle $\theta$ should be chosen so that $F_r(t)$ is either maximized or minimized. To see this, assume to the contrary that $F_r'(\theta)\neq 0$. Then, there is small $u$ (we allow $u$ to have negative sign) such that $$F_r(\theta-u)<1=F(\theta)<F_r(\theta+u).$$ If it is the case that $r\leq 1$, then by choosing slightly large $r'$, we can make $F_{r'}(\theta+u)=1$. This contradicts maximality of $r$. If $r>1$, then by choosing slightly large $r'$, we can make $F_{r'}(\theta-u) = 1$. This also leads to a contradiction. Now it follows that $\cos(2\theta)$ should be either $-1$ or $1$. However, we can easily see that $\cos(2\theta)$ cannot be $1$. Thus, from $\cos(2\theta)=-1$, we have
$$
1=F_r(\theta)=r^2 +r^{-2} -2 = (r-r^{-1})^2,
$$or
$$
r-1/r = \pm 1.
$$ This gives
$$
r= \frac{\pm 1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$ Therefore, the larger one $r=\frac{ 1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

$|z| =|z+1/z-1/z| \le$

$ |z+1/z| +|1/z| =1+|1/z|;$

$r:=|z|$;

$r-1/r \le 1;$

$r^2-r -1\le 0;$

$(r-1/2)^2 -1/4-1\le 0;$

$r-1/2 \le (1/2)√5;$

$r \le (1/2)(1+√5)$.

Is the maximum attained?

Comment: Very clear development. What is a simple argument to show that this is not just an upper bound but the maximum?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I'm thinking on a math-contest situation, how could we find an appropriate value that leads to this maximum value. It is not obvious. The solution using the optimization approach appears to me that address this difficulty.

Comment: bluemaster.Easy argument !? I try a bit so easy argument.Triangle inequality in the complex plane: Vector a=z , b=1/z .For side lengths of triangle formed by a,b and a+b (vectors): Since a triangle triangle inequality is strict((>).(lengths of sum of 2 sides of triangle is >than 3rd side.) Equality can only happen if a and b are collinear, We can try z= 1/2(1+√5)(real), does not work, but z= (1/2)(1+√5)i (purely imaginary), works to give |z+1/z|=1.Your thoughts?

Comment: Very good argument. I was struggling to see by the geometric interpretation and your thoughts clarified. The key is the situation in which a and b are collinear. Thanks!

Comment: bluemaster.Thanks! I was struggling too:))Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

We can maximize $g(a,b) = a^2+b^2$ subject to $(a^2+b^2)^2 =3b^2-1$. Solve for $a^2$ we have: $a^2= \sqrt{3b^2-1} -b^2\implies g(a,b) = \sqrt{3b^2-1}$. Thus the problem now is the find the maximum value of $b^2$. To this end, let $c = b^2 \ge 0$, we have: $a^4+2a^2c+c^2 - 3c+ 1 = 0\implies c^2-3c+1 \le 0\implies c \le \dfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\implies 3b^2 -1 = 3c-1\le \dfrac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}\implies |z|_{\text{max}} = \sqrt{g(a,b)}_{\text{max}} = \sqrt[4]{\dfrac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}}= \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$,and this max occurs when $a = 0$.

Comment: And just to compare with other solutions, it is true that $\sqrt[4]{\frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$